# Слияние двух бинарных деревьев

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево

Даны два бинарных дерева. Нужно построить 3 дерево, которое будет содержать только те узлы, которые есть в первом и во втором бинарном дереве.

```
using namespace std;

struct P_Node
{
    int key;
    P_Node *left;
    P_Node *right;
};
class Tree
{
public:
    P_Node *tree;
    Tree()
    {
        tree = NULL;
    }
    void PrintKey(P_Node *t)
    {
        cout << t->key << " ";
    }
    void preorder(P_Node *t) //обход в прямом порядке
    {
        if (t != 0)
        {
            PrintKey(t); // обработать корневой узел
            preorder(t->left);// обойти левое поддерево в нисходящем порядке
            preorder(t->right);//обойти правое поддерево в нисходящем пор-ке
        }
    }

    //вставка элемента
    void InsertInTree(P_Node **t, int k)
    {
        if (*t == 0)// если найдено место для нового узла
        {
            *t = new P_Node;// распределяем память
            (*t)->left = 0;// устанавливаем пустые ссылки для левого и
            (*t)->right = 0;// правого поддеревьев
            (*t)->key = k;// заполняем ключевое поле
        }
        /* иначе определяем, в каком поддереве узла t
        должен располагаться элемент с таким ключом */
        else
        {
            if (k <= (*t)->key)// если новый ключ меньше или равен текущему
            {
                InsertInTree(&((*t)->left), k);// вставим в левое поддерево
            }
            else
            {
                InsertInTree(&((*t)->right), k);// а иначе – в правое
            }
        }
    }

    P_Node *Del(P_Node **w, P_Node **t)// поиск самого правого элемента
    {
        if ((*w)->right != 0)
        {
            return Del(&((*w)->right), &(*t));
        }
        else
        {
            (*t)->key = (*w)->key;
            (*w) = (*w)->left;
            return *w;
        }
    }
        //функция слияния двух деревьев
        void Merge_trees();
    };

int main()
{
    Tree tree1;
    Tree tree2;
    Tree tree3;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: @goldstar_labs, как лучше всего реализовать эту функцию, чтобы  слияние не приводило  к дублированию ключей у разных узлов внутри одного и того же дерева?